# How to improve Django REST response processing time?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In a Django/DRF project, I am trying to improve the performance of an API endpoint that takes in a JSON file and creates model objects in the database from it. This JSON can be very large, spamming hundreds or thousands of entries. The view is using DRF's `ViewSet` class as the base.

I wrote a unit test with a fixture with around 800+ entries (so 800+ model objects) to investigate potential bottlenecks in the flow. By timing a few steps that I thought would be critical I found this:

```py
1) Time to create: 37.771371603012085
2) Time to check objects errors: 52.56421709060669
3) Time to create response: 0.499253511428833
4) Time Django processing response: 81.24804949760437
Time taken: 172.08289170265198
```

1. I can't use `bulk_create` because of multi-table inheritance
2. This is calling `full_clean()` on each object
3. Serialization of objects is irrelevant
4. After my function `return Response(...)`, all this time is spent on Django's backend

How can I improve step 4? I don't understand what takes so long to process the response and spit it back out.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you optimize your code without seeing any of it. One strategy is to put this work on an asynchronous worker (like celery) and more immediately return a response to the user. However there's no information here to determine if that's a reasonable path...it really depends on how the endpoint is being consumed.

Comment: There's no need to have any code snippet here because the number 4) is the Django REST framework backend processing my `return Response` statement so it's not really my code.